# Is there a Python/Numpy/other function for calculating the distance between two lines along a specified azimuth in the X, Y, and Z planes?

Tags: python, distance, azimuth

I am new to Python and am looking for a function that will calculate the distance between two roughly parallel lines along a specified azimuth in the X, Y, and Z directions. I see there are some functions to calculate the shortest distance between two points on adjacent lines. However, I need to calculate the distance between adjacent lines in a specified direction. The data is currently a set of points, roughly every 90 feet. I would like to measure the distances at least every 30 feet, and think I am able to obtain interpolated points where I am missing data. Interpolated data could come from straight lines (Euclidean distance?) connecting consecutive points.

I have been unable to find a function or workflow to accomplish this. Can anyone point me in the right direction to get started? Is this even possible?

Comment: We need informations about your data representation, ie is the line an equation or a set of points ?

Comment: Thank you for your help! The data is not an equation. It is currently a set of points, roughly every 90 feet. I would like to measure the distances at least every 30 feet, and think I am able to obtain interpolated points where I am missing data. Interpolated data could come from straight lines (Euclidean distance?) connecting consecutive points.